# How to online in facebook 24*7 by windows phone

Tags: facebook

When my phone is connected to Wifi,even then i dont get notification if someday pokes me in facebook.How to choose as a background task "allowed"

Comment: What phone and operating system do you use?

Comment: And what version of the facebook app are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone 8 by turns off your WiFi when the screen turns off to save battery. It automatically reconnects every now and then to check for incoming messages, but that's far from real-time. To keep your WiFi on even when the screen is off, go to Settings->WiFi->More->Keep WiFi on after screen timeout (note: off the top of my head, not the actual words from the operating system). Keep in mind that this will drain your battery faster unless you disable 3G while connected to WiFi.

Comment: And some customized versions doesn't have this option. My wife's HTC8X has this option from the begging but my Lumia 920 bought in Brazil only got this with the GDR2. And actually I heard that WiFi drain less battery than 3G.

Comment: @VitorCanova Turns out you are right! http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/15672/wi-fi-is-more-power-efficient-than-3g

Comment: WiFi and 3G will use more than just 3G though, of course.